# perl conditional regex check

Tags: regex, perl

```
<project name="kernel/lk" path="bootable/bootloader/lk" revision="e48c9314142c2ae93619ccd14aba2bc975165ffd"/>
<Project name="device/google/contexthub" revision="c453c8b8fb25fb8e1c59e8288331a70dbff44061" />
```

I have above two lines in a file.
I need to get the path and revision , If path is not available in the line it has to get the name and revision as output and save in a file

> Expected output :

```
name="kernel/lk" , revision="e48c9314142c2ae93619ccd14aba2bc975165ffd"
path="device/google/contexthub" , revision="c453c8b8fb25fb8e1c59e8288331a70dbff44061"
```

It will be great helpful,if someone gives me the code snippet.

Comment: Are you expecting us to write this for you? Not showing any of your attempts and where you failed?

Comment: This looks like `xml`. Is it? If so, then the tool for the job is `xpath` not `regex`. And even if not - don't try and execute conditionals in regex. Use the parent scripting language (e.g. perl)

Comment: [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) - use a parser

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code. If you don't have code, then perhaps Stack Overflow isn't the best place for your question. (Also, please don't parse XML with regexes.)

Comment: Why do people who can't write a parser insist on writing one themselves instead of using an existing one!? Use XML::LibXML!!!

Answer (score -1):

if ($row =~ m/name="(.+?)"\spath="(.+?)"\srevision="(.+?)"/g)
{
print "$1 $3\n";`test`
}`enter code here`
elsif ($row =~ m/name="(.+?)"\srevision="(.+?)"/g)
{`test`
print "$1 $2\n";
}
}`test`